# "SDK is not set" in comma IDE

Tags: raku, commaide

I'm trying to debug using Comma IDE, but I have run into this problem:

```
9:20    Error running 'Primera': SDK is not set
```

`Primera` is a configuration I have created (with defaults, mostly). I have looked through the menus, but I haven't found where I can set the SDK (or, for that matter, what is the SDK)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using comma as plugin:

File --> Project Structure --> Platform Settings --> SDKs

add ("+" sign)

I think setting SDK home path to perl6 bin should enough.

Comment: Still the same problem. I can't seem to be able to assign somehow that SDK to either the defaults or perl test profiles.

Comment: maybe restart IDE?

Comment: File --> Project Structure --> Project Settings --> Project --> Project SDK

Comment: That's what I did. The problem is that the recent rakudo release is marked as "Invalid". I've reported this to Edument team through  the tool itself.

Comment: from [irc log](https://colabti.org/irclogger/irclogger_log/perl6?date=2019-03-10#l340): Can you try to delete `.idea` folder from your project directory and then "Import" it?