# raku a graphical interface for WIndows 8

Tags: user-interface, graphics, raku, rakudo

I would like to download some sophisticated graphical interface for `Raku` for Windows 8.
Where can I find one ?
I have installed the following, which looks good, but I cannot currently run the oppened script:

[image]

[image]

**EDIT**

[image]

**EDIT 2**

[image]

I cannot enter the `path` to my project!
It doesn't appear in the list and dragging doesn't work.

**EDIT 3**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

To run a file in Comma you need to create an "environment" for it.

Comment: How do I do that ? I got this error: `No SDK for project`. See the left bottom corner of my second snippet.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55075395/sdk-is-not-set-in-comma-ide

Comment: Partial success. The error message has changed to that of my **EDIT** above. What now ?

Comment: Don't now. Can you post the Configuration window?

Comment: Where can I find `Configuration window` ? Note that I have been using `comma IDE` for one hour now.

Comment: Please see my **EDIT 2**.

Comment: **EDIT 3** I've now got yet a different error: 19:31 `Error running 'Test project2': No test source roots in the project: is it properly configured?`

Comment: @user2925716 That's a well known error, and it's related IIRC to the Java version you're running. Workaround: run the tests as a script, one by one.

Comment: @jjmerelo Oh thank you. Can you polopatically explain to me how do I do that ? You may write an entire answer as well.

Comment: A teď mi to řekni česky. - "And now in Czech".
We've got also an idiom polopatě (comes from po lopatě, lit. "by the shovel") which means to explain something very simply, slowly and comprehensively. So when you're afraid you won't understand something because of its complexity, you say: Řekni mi to polopatě. ("Tell me by the shovel") or when you explained something but the other seemingly didn't undestand so you have to repeat it, you say: Teď ti to řeknu ještě jednou a polopatě. ("Now I'll tell you again and by the shovel.").

Comment: @jjmerelo Right, so can you explain to me how can `I run tests as a script, one by one` ??

Comment: @user2925716 instead of "add test", use Comma's "add script". You'll have to add the -Llib flag in the corresponding slot. Scripts will run pretty much in the same way, except you'll not be able to jump from tests failures to the place where they were produced